# Markov Chains Probability Distributions Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I have a question that I didn't understand the solution for, that I'd love some help with!

The question:

> A hard-working GSI is holding her office hours. A random number of
> students enter and leave her office during her OH. Let us break up
> time into 1-minute segments, and assume that there is either 0 or 1
> student in each time segment, and that this discrete arrival/departure
> process is well modeled by a 2-state Markov Chain. For each time
> segment, the transition probabilities are 0.8 for going from 0
> students to 1 student in the OH, and 0.4 for going from 1 student to 0
> students in the OH.

I represented this with the transition matrix:
$P = \begin{pmatrix}
0.2 & 0.8\\
0.4 & 0.6
\end{pmatrix}$

The first subpart asked

> If the GSI starts off her office hours at t = 0 with 1 student, what
> is the probability that she has 0 student at time t = 2?

I did $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\end{pmatrix} P^2$ and got that at time=2, the state space distribution is $\begin{pmatrix}
0.36 & 0.64\end{pmatrix}$, so my final answer is 0.36. but the solution says 0.32, and they give their solution as: $0.4×0.2+0.6×0.4 = 0.32.$

For the second part of the question they ask:

> What does the probability go to, as t gets large, that there is 1 student?
> and give the solution:
> Answer: 0.8p0 +0.6p1 = p1 p0 = 1− p1
> This gives as 0.8(1− p1) +0.6p1 = p1 which gives p1 = 0.8/1.2 = 2/3.

Which I don't get either

Could I get clarification of where I went wrong and more explanation on where they got their solutions from? I'm also really shaky with Markov Chains in general, so conceptual explanations would help a lot too!

Comment: For the first part, you want $(0,1)P^2$, not $(1,0)P^2$ since we are told she starts with $1$ student at time $0$.

Comment: but then wouldnt I have to change my transition matrix? bc then the froms and tos will change

Comment: No, the first coordinate is the state where there are $0$ students, and the second the state where there is $1$.  Since we know there is one student in the office at time $0$, the probability that we are in state $2$ is $1$ and the probability that we are in state $1$ is $0$.  This is what the vector $(0,1)$ means.  If we were told that there is an $80\%$ change that there is a student in the office at time $0$, the initial state would be $(.2,.8)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part:  what are the possible paths?  Given that we start in state $1$ and end in state $0$ there are only two paths, namely $$1\mapsto 0\mapsto 0\quad \&\quad 1\mapsto 1\mapsto 0$$

The first has probability $.4\times .2=.08$ and the second has probability $.6\times .4=.24$ and the sum is $\boxed {.32}$.

For the second, we let $p_0,p_1$ be the equilibrium probabilities and note that we must have $$p_0=.2p_0+.4p_1\quad \&\quad p_1=.8p_0+.6p_1\quad \&\quad p_0+p_1=1$$ which implies $$\boxed {p_0=\frac 13\quad p_1=\frac 23}$$

Comment: x and y are $p_0$ and $p_1$ right

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Will edit.